# xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist

Tags: xcode, path, xcrun

I'm having Xcode issues when I try to use [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) and Git:

> xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)

I can type xcode-select and it shows that the command exists. When I type `xcode-select -p` it shows:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

but when I do `which xcode-select`, it gives me:

> /usr/bin/xcode-select

I've tried to use the command switch and install again via the Apple Developer site, but none of these options have worked so far... How can I fix this?

Answer (score 877):

I tried that, and it didn't work, but I found the answer. I just had to reset the developer's path:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Now everything is normal.

Comment: --reset normally this must be run as root

Comment: Thanks. I had uninstalled xcode and installed just the command line tools because I didn't need the whole xcode package on my mac with limited space. However, I was still unable to use commands such as gcc, but after running this command, it works like a charm

Comment: I just tried it; now I'm getting "SDK "macosx" cannot be located" lol

Comment: `--reset` works well for me. I need only the xcode cli for php development. So I decided to remove the complete xcode from my mac, then I downloaded only the xcode CLI installer(about 170MB). After I upgrade the installed xcode CLI via `app store`, and applied `sudo xcode-select --reset`, I am able to use `brew`and other command line tools such as `git` like before. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any danger in using --reset?

Comment: does not work ........

Comment: definitely worked!

Answer (score 233):

In my case, I had uninstalled Xcode and then issues with Git CLI started. I solved the problem running the following commands:

```
sudo xcode-select -r
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

And then validating a new path with:

```
sudo xcode-select -p
```

Comment: Worked for me after uninstalling xcode, saved my day

Comment: I was facing issues on Android Studio after I uninstalled XCode. Worked for me. I also had to restart Android Studio after using these commands.

Comment: This works for me after [having issue with node-gyp on macOS Catalina](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md)

Comment: i got message can't install the software. with the command i got `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'`

Answer (score 228):

Mostly this error occurs when you have installed a newer version of Xcode. And the command line tools are yet to be initialized.

To resolve this:
Go under Xcode *Preferences* → *Locations (tab)* → And the bottom options is *Command Line Tools*. Please select the Xcode version for tools.

**Example (for Xcode 10.0 (10A255)):
Go under Xcode *Preferences* → *Locations (tab)* → And the bottom options is *Command Line Tools*. Select Xcode 10.0 (10A255).**

For more details, please see this image:

[image: Select Command Line Tools]

Comment: I already see it as shown in the above image, but I still see the same error on my setup. I even tried resetting. Any idea? I

Comment: To do this programmatically (I had the error because I uninstalled Xcode), `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` (needs to be run as root)

Comment: I had to restart my IDE after I did this and then it worked.

Comment: The comment above is what fixed it for me

Answer (score 82):

I have faced the same issue as I have uninstalled the Xcode abruptly. Running the below command (from Terminal) helped me to resolve this.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```

Comment: Check this link also if you have any other error.
https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/23500

Comment: This worked for me. The problem was I uninstalled xcode in my mac. The command line is somehow still tied to xcode. So I went to ~library/Developer and deleted all folders and ran this command.

Answer (score 48):

This error is coming because Xcode gets deleted, corrupt or moved.
In my case I removed Xcode from my Mac and faced the same issue.

I fixed it by executing two simple steps:

1. Open Terminal
2. Simply run the following command

   ```
   sudo xcode-select -r
   ```

And now the error has been resolved.

Comment: It works for MacOS 12.4

Comment: This worked for me. I tried deleting XCode and reinstalling it, and got`xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist`.

Comment: Thank you for showing remove That ...... app from that ....... OSx

Answer (score 36):

Use this:

```sh
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Check this link also if you have any other error.
https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/23500

Comment: `xcode-select: error: missing argument to '-switch'
Usage: xcode-select [options]`

Answer (score 19):

Do what the error suggests. Try that:

```
xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: `--switch` must be run as root

Answer (score 7):

For me it helps to install Xcode CLI,

`xcode-select --install`

after uninstalling Xcode (I don't develop for the OS X or iOS).

Then I could successfully build the downloaded source with `make`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the error suggestion:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

And then test the Git executable path.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and had to remove Developer tools completely, and reinstall:

```
rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

Tip: because Xcode had been improperly uninstalled, I had to manually (re)move the Xcode app, too:

```
mv /Applications/Xcode.app/ /Applications/Xcode.app.bak
```

Comment: The installation of the xcode gui app definitely was part of the issue for me. I got rid of it and re-installed xcode-select from scratch and everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

In my case such error occurred after I has tried to ***symbolicate crash report***, and according to a manual, entered command `export DEVELOPER_DIR=”/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer”`

I tried some proposed here solutions but nothing helped.

Then I realized that I have added an environment variable `DEVELOPER_DIR` to my terminal and this led to error: *"xcrun: error: missing DEVELOPER_DIR path:"*

Then I've **just reboot my terminal**, that cleaned the environment variable and the error disappeared.

(FYI: environment variables may be checked with `printenv` command in terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

**sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app**

[image: Check this out]

Comment: sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app (space before --) - did not work anyway

Comment: Works as expected, `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` is also written in the XCode errors report.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75995543/edit) (it covers answers as well, including textual output). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For my [MacBook Pro M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Sixth_generation_(M1)) [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) for the case, I already tried all the previous answers and it was not solved.

I have solved it by the discussion in *[Unable to install Xcode command line developer tools](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660641)*.

There is have two options to solve, in my case...

1. I have uninstalled Xcode, because I don't need it again
2. install standalone mode, but it doesn’t work: *"can't install the software"*
3. It was **solved by** trying to download it manually by command line tools. Check on the discussion thread for the link file (741.5 MB).