# Cocoa pod command gives error in Catalina os , xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have downloaded the latest version of Xcode in Catalina os but the issue is "pod install" command not working on terminal

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    4: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49:in `run'
    1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:130:in `verify_minimum_git_version!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:118:in `git_version': Failed to extract git version from `git --version` ("xcrun: error: active developer path (\"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer\") does not exist\nUse `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.\nSee `man xcode-select` for more details.\n") (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Read the error. It tells you exactly what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I'm stuck nothing happen anything in  that steps

Comment: Mostly this error occurs when you have installed a newer version of xcode. And the command line tools are yet to be initialized.

To resolve this: Go under Xcode Preferences > Locations (tab) > And the bottom options is Command Line Tools. Please select the Xcode version for tools.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009531/xcrun-error-active-developer-path-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below command is going to help you.

sudo xcode-select --install

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed command line tools?

If not then first install it by executing this command in terminal :

```
 xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 1):

just do this in terminal and it will work:=

```
    sudo xcode-select --install
```